# Where do I find thousands of blue & yellow bricks for an art project?

Tags: bricklink, pick-a-brick, bricks-and-pieces, lugbulk

I'm an artist and I've started a project where I need around 4000 blue and yellow bricks, specifically bricks and plates that are 2x or 1x any length, but the longer the better. Any suggestions on where to find these for the best possible price?

NOTE: I've purchased several used bulk lots on eBay, but on a price per brick I need basis, this isn't very cost effective. I've also gone to the LEGO store, but I you really can't get many larger bricks in those little cups, plus I actually prefer the look of used bricks. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. I don't have a lot of money as I'm a college professor, but I am having my first solo museum exhibition next fall and I'd really like to include this piece. (Sadly, unless you're world famous, museums don't pay a penny for artists materials.)

Comment: You'd probably enjoy this talk, about an art project, a programmer made his wife a picture of her out of LEGO bricks. http://devslovebacon.com/conferences/bacon-2013/talks/tetris-in-real-lego tl-dr; A: you can order bricks by colour B: a couple of pennies per brick really ramp up in price. C: Work out exactly how many you need to get them at the cheapest available price.

Answer (score 17):

Try BrickLink.com, the Online LEGO Marketplace. It works like eBay, with buyers and sellers from all over the world. You can buy the exact pieces you need, in the quantity and condition you need.

Since you want a large bulk of parts, I would suggest that you post your request on the BrickLink Forum first, as there may be sellers who have a very large quantity of what you want, but haven't listed in their stores (sellers like to focus on listing their more expensive stock first).

Most BrickLink sellers are good people and they would be happy to help out with a project like yours and offer very reasonable prices. It is also beneficial for them, as they can get rid of a large quantity of their stock at one time (especially if you are happy with used elements). So it's a win-win for everyone involved.

Answer (score 3):

The cheapest option would be to join your local RLUG and participate in the lugbulk program, however given the time constraint of having an exposition already next fall this might not be feasible (lugbulk takes nearly a year to organize, order, deliver, sort, etc...)

The next best solution would then be to visit your lego store again and ask the personnel for several bulk cases of bricks. These are the same cases they use to fill up the wall. They calculate the price so it roughly matches the price you would pay if you filled the cups very efficiently (you can roughly fit 130 2x4 bricks in a large cup). So not much discount but it saves you a lot of time.

Comment: LUGBULK is a great suggestion for the future, but I can confirm that the timeline won't work in this case. LUGBULK orders for 2018 were finalized on the 31st of January for delivery later this year. It will be at least a year and a half before @EyeJelly could get in on and receive an order.

Comment: Who or what is RLUG? [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLUG) doesn't know. Regional Lego *something* Lugbulk?

Comment: Hope this helps explaining: http://thebrickblogger.com/2015/10/lego-lugbulk-the-best-way-to-build-big/